# Is it valid to resample a raster from 1m to 3 feet?

Tags: raster, dem, gis-principle, resampling

I know that in general it is not a good idea to up-sample. I am curious if it would still be be a "bad idea" with a minor change like this from 1m resolution to 3 feet? Going to 3 feet would not actually be up-sampling anyway. Three feet should be slightly less than 1 meter. Would you recommend against this or is this perfectly valid? I am contemplating doing this with a 1M DEM.

I found many questions about resampling but most involve obvious down sampling. This would be more like changing projection from a Raster in units of meters to a raster in units of feet and rounding to 3 feet (that is how I thought to proceed).

If there is error involved, is there any way (preferably easy) of quantifying how much has been introduced by this method?

Comment: All data conversions entail some kind of error. But if we don't do it at all we wont' be able to standardize our different data components in a project. I say the key is in documenting what you did and giving it as caveat or simply disclosing the steps you took to get your resolution in 3ft from a 1m DEM. The end user will then assess if it is within their error tolerance. Short answer:  Do it but document it.

Comment: I have gone the other way, say from 3 feet, to 1 meter, and from 1 meter to 3 meters pixel sizes, with reasonable success, especially when I applied this to Digital Elevation Models, however, going the other way may take a little bit more work than you may wish to do.
I would generate a new Triangulated Irregular Network to begin with, or generate a new set of dense contours to create the new DEM at the interval you desire. This can be very involved, and prone to error without some very powerful terrain modeling software, and a great deal of patience.

Comment: On second thought, you would just be better off leaving the DEM at one meter resolution, reprojecting the data to whatever you need, and dealing with 3.280833 ft. pixel resolution. I think you would have very bad cumulative errors if the terrain was anything less than smooth. If you had raw data, you could sample it any way you would like.